# Legenda animada com hover

Tags: css, css3, css-hover

Tenho uma imagem e adicionei uma legenda interativa a ela.

Criei a `div class="legenda_interna"` com o mesmo tamanho da imagem. Exibo somente `30%` do tamanho dela e o resto quero ocultar. Quero exibir somente o trecho com o botão.

Quando eu passar o mouse, o `:hover` exibe todo o conteúdo.

Vejam o snippet:

```css
html, body{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.principal{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:40%;
  height:50%;
  background: url('http://imagens.canaltech.com.br/50648.69556-IMagem-Exemplo-Exposicao.jpg') center no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  }

.legenda_interna{
 position: relative;
 width:100%; 
 height:100%; 
 opacity: 0.6; 
 top: 70%; 
 background-color: #212c42;
 -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: ease-out 0.5s;
    transition: ease-out 0.5s;
}

.botao_interno{
 padding: 8px;
 margin-top: 10px;
 width: 170px;
 background: transparent;
 color: white;
 border: 2px solid white;

}

.legenda_interna:hover{ 
 top: 0px;
 -webkit-transition: ease-out 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: ease-out 0.5s;
    transition: ease-out 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="principal"> 
  <div class="legenda_interna"> 
   <center>       
    <button class="botao_interno">EXIBIR SOMENTE AQUI</button>
    <p style="color:red; margin-top:50px">ESTE CONTEÚDO SÓ APARECE COM O :HOVER</p>
              <p style="color:red; margin-top:5px">ESTE CONTEÚDO SÓ APARECE COM O :HOVER</p>
              <p style="color:red; margin-top:5px">ESTE CONTEÚDO SÓ APARECE COM O :HOVER</p>
  
            </center>
 </div>
</div>
```

Como eu poderia ocultar o conteúdo depois do botão e exibí-lo somente ao passar o mouse sobre a div?

Comment: já tentou usar a propriedade `overflow:hidden`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicione na sua div com a classe `.principal` a propriedade `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: Já vi muitos códigos utilizando este atributo e nunca sabia o porque do seu uso. Agora sei qual é rsrs Obrigado!

Comment: Sim ela é muito utilizada para criar slides e outros tipos de animações, dá pra criar efeitos bem legais com ela.

Answer (score 1):

Adicione a propriedade em:

```
.legenda_interna{
   ...
   overflow:hidden; /* isto vai esconder todo o conteúdo que seja filho deste que possa sair fora deste elemento
   ...
}
```